# Incremented value inside if statement doesn't display on else statement

Tags: php

I have a Reverse loop on PHP, and i can't seem to get the value which i have incremented on the if statement to my else statement.

this is my code.

```
<?php
$r = 0;
$data = array("false","false","false","true");
for( $x = count($data)-1; $x >= 0; $x-- ) {
    if('false' === $data[$x]) {
    $r++;
    }
    else {
        echo $r;
    }
}
?>

output: 0
expected output: 3
```

I have tried to use a normal loop to check if the issue is on the scope of the variable, but the expected output is correct.

```
<?php
$r = 0;
$data = array("false","false","false","true");
for( $x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++ ) {
    if('false' === $data[$x]) {
    $r++;  
    }
    else {
        echo $r;
    }
}
?>

output: 3
expected output: 3
```

Can you Advise? thanks

Comment: If you want to display the final value of `$r`, move it outside the for loop. Currently `$r` is displaying the value when the iterated value is true, which is 3rd when starting from begining and 0 when starting from last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you start loop last to first index,

first value of your loop is `true` so its go on else part and display `0` after that all time go on `if` part and `$r++` but not to display if you print `$r` outside loop its value is `3`

```
<?php
    $r = 0;
    $data = array("false","false","false","true");
    for( $x = count($data)-1; $x >= 0; $x-- ) {
        if('false' === $data[$x]) {
            $r++;
        }
        else {
            echo $r; //first time print this because condition false
        }
   }
   echo $r; //its value 3 here

?>
```

Comment: thanks, i was also able to solve it right after i posted it. i don't know what went wrong with my mind. :D anyways, your answer proves my answer. thanks!

Comment: if you find it helpful than please accept the answer. @JohnOtom